# PHP function not working, several arguments, array return

Tags: php, sql, arrays, function

```
<?php
function calculateTotals($column,$rowStart,$rowEnd,$boolSim) {
$queryTotalPage = "SELECT SUM(`" . $column . "`) FROM `mylogbook` WHERE `flightNumber` >= " . $rowStart . " AND `flightNumber` <= " . $rowEnd . " AND `simulator` = " . $boolSim;
$resultTotalPage = mysql_query($queryTotalPage) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultTotalPage)){
    $totalTimeHoursPage = floor($row["SUM(" . $column . ")"]/60);
    $totalTimeMinutesPage = sprintf('%02d', ($row["SUM(" . $column . ")"] % 60));
}
$queryTotalPreviousPages = "SELECT SUM(`" . $column . "`) FROM `mylogbook` WHERE `flightNumber` >= 1 AND `flightNumber` < " . $rowStart . " AND `simulator` = " . $boolSim;
$resultTotalPreviousPages = mysql_query($queryTotalPreviousPages) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultTotalPreviousPages)){
    $totalTimeHoursPreviousPages = floor($row["SUM(" . $column . ")"]/60);
    $totalTimeMinutesPreviousPages = sprintf('%02d', ($row["SUM(" . $column . ")"] % 60));
}
$queryTotal = "SELECT SUM(`" . $column . "`) FROM `mylogbook` WHERE `flightNumber` >= 1 AND `flightNumber` <= " . $rowEnd . " AND `simulator` = " . $boolSim;
$resultTotal = mysql_query($queryTotal) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultTotal)){
    $totalTimeHours = floor($row["SUM(" . $column . ")"]/60);
    $totalTimeMinutes = sprintf('%02d', ($row["SUM(" . $column . ")"] % 60));
}
return array($totalTimeHoursPage,$totalTimeMinutesPage,$totalTimeHoursPreviousPages,$totalTimeMinutesPreviousPages,$totalTimeHours,$totalTimeMinutes);
}
// TEST calculate totals
echo "TEST CALC";
calculateTotals("timePIC","1","100","0");
echo $calculateTotals[0];
?>
```

This function worked previously being single blocks of code. Now I tried changing it to a generic function. No errors are produced. The output array of the function seems empty.

Comment: You sure your queries are running correctly? Do you have error reporting on (`ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not storing output of function call to anywhere and trying to do `echo`.

You should store returned output to some variable ( let say, `$calculateTotals`) and then do `echo`

```
echo "TEST CALC";
$calculateTotals = calculateTotals("timePIC","1","100","0");
echo $calculateTotals[0];
```

This should work.

Comment: Many thanks! That solved it, off course!

Comment: Most welcome dude.. then don't forgot to mark it as answer. :)